# Is there a good resource for constructions using double-edged straightedge?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Double-edged straightedge constructions use only a straightedge, but use the fact that a straightedge has two parallel sides that are a fixed with apart. I've found one obscure paper from the 80s that describes it, but I know there are other resources out there. Do you know of any?

Comment: Is this asking if the classical Euclidean constructibility results are changed if a double-edged straightedge is allowed?

Comment: A quick Google search turned up [this Masters thesis by Sandra Kay Birrell in 1983](https://scholarworks.calstate.edu/downloads/0c483n19f) from p50 (p58 of the pdf) - perhaps what you were referring to, but I think this is all well known - I remember discussing it at school in the 1970s

Comment: @FShrike I suspect the point is that with a double straight edge, you do not need a compass (allowing a slight change to what constitutes a circle to being its centre and a point a given distance away)

Comment: It's asking more for a guide on how to do constructions using both sides of a straightedge but without a compass. @Henry That is the thesis I also found, but I'm sure I've read other more accessible resources in the past.